# Extract specific fields from tables in bigquery when FROM section contains tables with identically named fields

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to ex

```
SELECT
field1, --comes from table A
field2, --comes from table B
field3, --I want to grab this from table A, but table B has an identically named field
FROM
[datasetName.tableA],
[datasetName.tableB],
```

I've tried

```
SELECT
t1.field1, --comes from table A
t2.field2, --comes from table B
t1.field3, --I want to grab this from table A, but table B has an identically named field
FROM
[datasetName.tableA] t1,
[datasetName.tableB] t2,
```

But that generates the error

```
Incompatible types. 'duration' : TYPE_DOUBLE 'duration' : TYPE_INT64
```

I'm not sure the best way to handle this.  I could add a second level to the select statement so that the structure would be like

```
SELECT
field1,
field3
[datasetName.tableA],
UNION ALL
SELECT
field2,
[datasetName.tableB],
```

But because the actual query I'm working with is much more complicated than this toy example, that's not optimal for code readability.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks,
Brad

Comment: at least the issue I see here is that you are mixing JOIN related notions (in SELECT statement) with UNION (in FROM). Can you please provide specific example of input and output so we have chance to help then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you want to do JOIN vs. UNION (note: in BigQuery Legacy SQL - comma means UNION ALL)

Try somethig like below

```
SELECT
  t1.field1 AS field1,
  t2.field2 AS field2,
  t1.field3 AS field3
FROM [datasetName.tableA] t1
JOIN [datasetName.tableB] t2
ON t1.somefield = t2.anotherfield
```

make sure you replace somefield and anotherfield with actual fields in respective tables

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something here conceptually, but I'm not trying to do a join.  What I want to accomplish is extract particular fields from different tables, but I don't require those tables to have a particular relationship to each other.  What I want to be able to do is extract a specific field from a specific table, it's just that field name happens to be replicated across two different tables.

Comment: Although I *could* accomplish this using a join, I was actively trying to do it using UNION ALL instead of JOIN because it seemed like an easier way to accomplish my goal.  But maybe it isn't.  So maybe that's just what I need to do.

Comment: if you can better present your case/logic with specific example - this can help :o)

Comment: We have a bunch of user data, but the data from those users is split across various different tables- one table for different kinds of user events.  This is because a lot of the events are basically housekeeping events and most of the time we don't want to look at them, so by having event_specific tables we can keep our query sizes smaller and much faster.

Comment: The problem though, is when I want to query across a bunch of different tables because I want to look at behaviour that is described within a session but across different kinds of user events for a given, I can then either look at the parental table that contains all the events or I can try to do something like this: union a bunch of the tables together that contain only the events that I'm interested in.

Comment: But some of those tables have identically named fields that actually contain data that has different meaning (not my design).  

Alternatively, I could go back and use the single large table that contains everything and accept that the query size and cost will go up, but those tables have all the fields i need in nested fields, so then parsing them out is a huge PITA, esp. if any debugging ends up being required.

Comment: So the 'solution' that I was trying seems non-optimal because the data organization and schema wasn't optimal in the first place.  I'm trying to come up w/ a hacky-ish solution for a one time problem versus spending a bunch more time coming up w/ an elegant solution that I'll never need to use again.  But I may just have to do that anyway.

Comment: I'll just kill this question and I'll try to reformulate the problem a totally different way.

Comment: yes. the issue in your case with using union is that tabels should be compatible by schema (datatypes, etc.) which is not a case here

Comment: Right, which now I can see is exactly what bigquery was telling me, I just didn't catch that.  Thanks for your help and time.

Comment: Ah, yes, of course.  You did help me out even though it didn't address my initial question because you helped me recognize the problem with my question.  It doesn't have a direct solution. So thank you and I voted it up and accepted it.